# Java: Why does calling `remove()` on a List throw UnsupportedOperation exception?

Tags: java

For some reason, I'm getting an `UnsupportedOpeationException` with the following code. Examining it in the debugger, it looks like the object I'm calling `remove()` on is a list.

```
// to optimize, remove totalSize. After taking an item from lowest, if lowest is empty, remove it from `lists`
// lists are sorted to begin with
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<T> merge(Set<List<T>> lists) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    HashMap<List<T>, Integer> location = new HashMap<List<T>, Integer>();

    int totalSize = 0; // every element in the set
    for (List<T> l : lists) {
        location.put(l, 0);
        totalSize += l.size();
    }

    boolean first;
    List<T> lowest = lists.iterator().next(); // the list with the lowest item to add
    int index;

    while (result.size() < totalSize) { // while we still have something to add
        first = true;

        for (List<T> l : lists) {
            if (! l.isEmpty()) {
                if (first) {
                    lowest = l;
                }
                else if (l.get(location.get(l)).compareTo(lowest.get(location.get(lowest))) <= 0) {
                    lowest = l;
                }
            }
        }
        index = location.get(lowest);
        result.add(lowest.get(index));
        lowest.remove(index); //problem here
    }
    return result;
}
```

The exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.remove(Unknown Source)
    at interview.questions.MergeLists.merge(MergeLists.java:72)
    at interview.questions.MergeLists.main(MergeLists.java:32)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Let's see the code that is calling this method.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's quite possible the underlying implementation of `List` you received is fixed-length, such as one created by [`Arrays#asList`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29).

Comment: yeah, that's what it comes from actually. What can I do to prevent this from being a problem?

Comment: The most simplistic approach would be to copy each of the input Lists to a modifiable form such as a `new LinkedList<T>(l)`.  A better approach might be to create a new class to act as a peekable iterator that is comparable according to the iteration's current element, create an instance of it for each input list, and toss the lot into a `PriorityQueue`.  Then, the inner loop becomes simple: pull the next item from the queue, append its element to the output, advance it, and if it hasn't hit end of list put it back in the queue (letting the `PriorityQueue` sort for you).

Comment: Thanks!! I was having the same issue from Hibernate trying to remove from the list on a merge(). I was using Arrays#asList when setting up some test data in a unit test.... +1, wish I could +100!!!

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the [API docs for the List interface](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) you will see that a number of them are "optional operations".  That means that a concrete class is permitted to throw the UnsupportedOperationException.

If, for example, the List was converted to an [unmodifiable list](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29) it could not allow the remove operation to actually remove something (or the list would be modified).

So for the Set< List<>> part of the code one or mnre of the lists does not allow you to remove from it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to be removing items from a List, then rather than use a for-each loop to iterate through the list, you should be using a ListIterator, which supports remove() in a safe manner (i.e. without leaving holes in the list or an index pointing to nowhere).

Comment: Just curious, why the downvote?  It's a valid recommendation... maybe doesn't answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

It is optional for a class implementing the Collection interface to allow objects to be removed (see [`Collection#remove()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) which is an optional operation). As stated in the javadoc, it throws

> [`UnsupportedOperationException`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) - if the `remove` operation is not supported by this collection

You are likely in that case (e.g. if your set contains a list returned by [`Arrays.asList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) as pointed out by Jeffrey).

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the Lists you pass in the set are derived from `AbstractList` and do not implement (support) the `remove()` method?

Also, it seems that `location` always maps to `0` for all list object that are mapped in the location HashMap?

Answer (score 0):

The remove() method in the Collection interface is explicitly specified as an optional operation:

```
remove(Object o)
          Removes a single instance of the specified element from this collection, if it is present (optional operation).
```

Lists do not have to support in. In fact, there is no clear semantics for it. Lists are not meant for that sort of random-access. Rather than provide some default implementation that may be inefficient or inaccurate, you get the exception.

You can write your own utility method with a for-each loop to do this if it is critical.